# how to find the favicon of a website with python with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, favicon

i need to do a little program that would be able to find the favicon of a website like the one of YouTube or google but i didn't found any exemple on google i already tried to do a code that can find picture on Wikipedia with Beautifulsoup but not the little image of the title.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674460/how-to-get-favicon-by-using-beautiful-soup-and-python

Comment: it wasn't me but can i delet the question just after we answer my last question that i ask. please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get favicon by using beautiful soup and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674460/how-to-get-favicon-by-using-beautiful-soup-and-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need bs4.

The icon is just a static file with the name "favicon.ico" .

For exsample, the favicon of stack overflow is at "www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico"

And the favicon of Google is at "www.google.com/favicon.ico"

etc.

Comment: thanks i test it and it works but on some website like www.tommy.com or  or roborock https://en.roborock.com/favicon.ico it doesn't work do they use a different technologie or not? thanks

Comment: Sorry， I don't know about this :( .I guess it's only for HTML sites, and not other (e.g. CMS) ,you can take a look at this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/4674902/13108758

Comment: thanks, you have progress for the reputation, i hope for you that it will continue.