# how to grab icon from the tab (not from the website content)

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, icons

When you open most of the websites, there is a tiny icon on a left side of the tab (and name to the right). For example for website: http://www.prairieventures.net/ you can see the tiny icon
here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQoSn.png .Is there a way to grab it automatically?

I know how to use beautiful soup and also tried api like favicon and clearbit but for this specific website (and many others) it returns wrong image (big picture with the field) as opposed to the tiny icon on the tab that I'm after. Clearbit is even more cheeky and shrinks the big image so it looks like an icon. Inspecting elements grabs stuff from web content but since what I want is usually not there (because it on the tab) I have no idea how to grab it. Could anybody give me any help please? Ideally in python but happy to broad my horizon.

Comment: You mean [this image](http://www.prairieventures.net/wp-content/themes/pv/images/logo-prairie-ventures.png)?

Comment: most of which websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to reply to your comment so posting here.

I don't think you understood my answer. When I say "favicon" I don't mean the favicon api, favicon is the name of the small image you are trying to scrape, see:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

If you are trying to get the full path to the image you can search for the line I mentioned in my previous reply and extract the contents of the href tag.

If you need further help you will need to give more details as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: that was helpful and it should work, but not sure why I still get wrong image. For example thanks to your tip I can now find link to what supposed to be an icon (<link href="https://static.parastorage.com/client/pfavico.ico" rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon"/> but when I check the link, the icon is blank, while the icon on the tab of the same link is clearly visible and colourful

Comment: Aha! Thank you my friend - your method works fine for all the examples where website is not build dynamically. Thank you so much for your help - thanks to you I can now find at least most of them :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the favicon which is the small 16x16 pixel image shown next to the webpage title in browser tabs. On many sites you can simply access it by appending favicon.ico onto the end of the web address, for example:

http://www.prairieventures.net/favicon.ico

If you need to **scrape** it you can look for the following line in the pages html:

```
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="http://www.prairieventures.net/wp-content/themes/pv/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

This also shows the image file location on the site.

For a discussion on scraping favicons using beautiful soup and python see:

[How to get favicon by using beautiful soup and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674460/how-to-get-favicon-by-using-beautiful-soup-and-python)

Comment: As I said, I already used favicon - its very inconsistent and in the case I mentioned it returns wrong result

Answer (score -1):

In your browser, go to:

Tools > Page Info> Media

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This seems to be a browser specific thing. I don't see this option in Edge. Also, I think the point is to see what the url of the favicon is. All this is stuff you can add to your answer instead of meta-commentary.